# Find the remainder of a sum of factorials divided by $35$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What will be the remainder of
>   $$1!+2!+3!+\dots+2009!$$ 
>   is divided by $35$?

Comment: I think your caps lock got stuck. Jokes aside, please format your question normally. This is bound to attract downvotes. Also, please show your work - what have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck? This isn't a simple question and answer website, it's supposed to *help* you with questions, not downright throwing the answer in your lap.

Comment: Hint: all factorials from $7!$ up are divisible by 35.

Answer (score 2):

As a **hint**, note that all factorials starting from $7!$ will be divisible by $35$ as they contain both the factors $5$ and $7$. Now all that remains is to compute $\sum_{i=1}^{6} i!$ and find the remainder by dividing with $35$.